# "Unknown property value" error when using CSS3 gradient

Tags: css, gradient

I am using a linear gradient for a rectangular div, as shown below:

```css
.rectangle {
  width:            300px;
  height:           200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to-right, #009A80 0%, #333 0%, #333 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

However the background does not render. In the Chrome dev tools it says "Unknown property value". I am assuming something is wrong with the syntax but couldn't find the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the hyphen in the first argument of linear-gradient, 'to-right'.

**See the code below:**

```css
.rectangle {
  width:            300px;
  height:           200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #009A80 0%, #333 0%, #333 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it was something trivial.

Answer (score 2):

> Always try using deg or rad for the gradient direction , since it will provide the all kind of directions .
> if you want to write using the words , then there is **no hyphen** in between the '**to-right**'.
> It will be `to right` .
> if you are using degree you can try (0deg,#111,#333,#444)

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #009A80 0%, #333 0%, #333 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```